# jQuery drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using JQuery draggable.  If a table is in div then I can move this div with the table.  When there is an input-button in the div then it doesnt move.  Why?

```
$(".multidraggable").draggable();
```

doesnt work:

```
<div class="multidraggable" style="display: inline-block;">
    <input type="button" value="Отчет за &#10; контрактные сутки &#10; без ТГК &rdquo;УрГРЭС&rdquo;" id="button1" style="font-family:arial; width: 200px; height: 80px;max-height:80px;max-width:200px; font-size:15" />
</div>
```

works:

```
<div class="multidraggable" style="display: inline-block;">
        <table id="maintable" frame="box" border="1" style="height: 565px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
            <thead>
                <tr style="background-color:#ffe45c url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_ffe45c_1x100.png);">
                    <th>
...
</div>
```

Comment: Without seeing any code it is impossible to say! There could be a huge number of reasons.

Comment: check the id or class of your input button

Comment: Shouldn't the `jquery-ui` tag be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used to make something draggable, maybe it will help you...

```
// make items draggable...   
    $("#CmsDynamicToolbarItems").find("ul li")   
        .draggable({ containment: "#CanvasAreaCoverPage",    
            snap: true,    
            scroll: false,    
            helper: "clone",    
            revert: "invalid",    
            opacity: 1.0,    
            cursor: "move"    
        });
```

There could be various reasons, but things like cloning the item, containing the element can help, but they are not really needed. I would select the id of the html element first, then add draggable to it, then start to use classes for draggable.

Answer (score 0):

found solution:

To make your input draggable, override the cancel option:

```
$("#myinput").draggable({ cancel: null });
```